# PHP regex - replace all text between a tag

Tags: php, regex

I have a link being outputted on my site, what i want to do is replace the visible text that the user sees, but the link will always remain the same.

There will be many different dynamic urls with the text being changed, so all the example regex that i have found so far only use exact tags like '/.*/'...or something similar

Edited for a better example

```
$link = '<a href='some-dynamic-link'>Text to replace</a>';
$pattern = '/#(<a.*?>).*?(</a>)#/';
$new_text = 'New text';
$new_link = preg_replace($pattern, $new_text, $link);
```

When printing the output, the following is what i am looking for, against my result.

Desired

```
<a href='some-dynamic-link'>New text</a>
```

Actual

```
'New text'
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: What's your PHP usage? The `.` doesn't match a newline if the `s` modifier isn't used. You also may want to use a parser.

Comment: The problem is this is replacing the entire tag and is deleting the <a href=...The only thing i want to change is the display text between the a tag and leave the link intact

Comment: You probably need to add the capture groups back to the replacement value. Without PHP usage we have no idea what you are doing though..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you're already using the capture groups, why not actually *use* them.

```
$link = "<a href='some-dynamic-link'>Text to replace</a>";
$newText = "Replaced!";
$result = preg_replace('/(<a.*?>).*?(<\/a>)/', '$1'.$newText.'$2', $link);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you needs to get everything in Between tags then you can use below function

```
<?php
    function getEverything_inBetween_tags(string $htmlStr, string $tagname)
    {
        $pattern = "#<\s*?$tagname\b[^>]*>(.*?)</$tagname\b[^>]*>#s";
        preg_match_all($pattern, $htmlStr, $matches);
        return $matches[1];
    }
    $str = '<a href="test.com">see here for more details about test.com</a>';
    echo getEverything_inBetween_tags($str, 'a');

   //output:- see here for more details about test.com
?>
```

if you needs to extract HTML Tag & get Array of that tag

```
<?php 
    function extractHtmlTag_into_array(string $htmlStr, string $tagname)
    {
        preg_match_all("#<\s*?$tagname\b[^>]*>.*?</$tagname\b[^>]*>#s", $htmlStr , $matches);
        return $matches[0];
    }

    $str = '<p>test</p><a href="http://test.com">test.com</a><span>testing string</span>';
    $res = extractHtmlTag_into_array($str, 'a');
    print_r($res);

   //output:- Array([0] => "<a href="https://www.amazon.in/Amazon-Brand-Solimo-liner-brush/dp/B08GLHM9SF?=&amp;src=test.in&amp;=&amp;=">amazon.in/xyz/abc?test=abc</a>") 
?>
```